# Alternative for maintaining separate constants for field names

Tags: java, android, realm, pojo

While using Sqlite as DB in android, Many of us create a class like DbConstants where we save all the Table names, column names as constants.

In case of Realm DB, we prepare POJO classes which are represented as tables and fields as column names respectively.

Is there any way though which i can avoid creating another constants file here ?

Use Case :

POJO representing User table :

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

private String          name;
private int             age;

@Ignore
private int             sessionId;

// Standard getters & setters generated by your IDE…
public String getName() { return name; }
public void   setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
public int    getAge() { return age; }
public void   setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
public int    getSessionId() { return sessionId; }
public void   setSessionId(int sessionId) { this.sessionId = sessionId;       
 }
}
```

so while we query User table as follows :

```
RealmResults<User> result = realm.where(User.class)
                              .equalTo("name", "John")
                              .or()
                              .equalTo("name", "Peter")
                              .findAll();
```

I don`t want to use the literals like “name” here. So any other elegant solution or best practice ?

Comment: Your setters/getters indicate you are not familiar with Lombok: https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski That POJO is straight from the Realm docs :) . Although mine ones are not any different. Thanks for the interesting link !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual practice is having a static final constant in your model class like this:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
  public static final String NAME = "name";
  public static final String AGE = "age";

  // Fields, constructors, getters, setters,
}

realm.where(Person.class).equalTo(Person.NAME, "John").findAll();
```

If you want an automated way of doing it you can take a look at: https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper

Comment: I really want to use this helper tool, but it says it works with Realm 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Right now it only work with our SNAPSHOT release. We will release Realm 1.1.1 probably today. It will also work with that.

Comment: fingers crossed !!

Comment: Realm Java 1.1.1 has been released, and the library should also work with that.